# Encrypt string to fixed length

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, base64

I want to encrypt string to base64, the string input can be in differential length(the limit is 16 charcters), and I want to get the encrypted string in fixed length.

Does anyone know about the way to do that in .NET framework? or has an algorithm to do that?

Comment: base64 is *encoding*, not encryption (meaning that it does not give you any security). It is used to convert a binary data to a textual one (i.e. one that uses inly printable characters). Is this what you need?

Comment: Do unicode codepoints outside the basic plane count as two characters or only one? A unicode codepoint doesn't fit one 16 bit char.

Comment: Is it your input string that is limited to 16 characters, or your output string?  If your input is limited to 16 characters, what you seek is doable with care.  If your output is limited to 16 bytes but your inputs are not, then you are not dealing with (reversible) encryption but with hashing.  And 16 bytes of Base-64 encoding can only contain 96 bits, so your choices of hash algorithm are a bit constained (or you have to chop the value produced by a longer algorithm to 96 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for 1-way encryption (no need to decrypt), you can use SHA1

```
        string secretKey = "MySecretKey";
        string salt = "123";
        System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
        byte[] preHash = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(secretKey + salt);
        byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(preHash);
        string password = System.Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

If you want to encrypt and decrypt, you could probably use RSA.

Comment: Why do you think that someone who wants to use base64, should use SHA ?

Comment: I always understand the term "encryption" to mean two way - this is just a hash. Still, no -1 as it *may* be what the OP wants and has expressed badly.

Comment: @Vash, from my understanding, he wants to encrypt and then convert to base64. He said "I want to encrypt string to base64". If he said he wanted to encode, then we don't need SHA1.

Comment: @Fun: If he'd wanted a one-way hash, I hope he'd have said so :)

Comment: @jon-skeet, hashing may be suitable if his purpose is to store some secret code that can be verified later without compromising the actual secret. I got this idea from his requirement of a fixed length output. It may still be possible that he wanted 2-way for which I had mentioned RSA.

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng, fair enough, thanks for pointing that out. But I still think that sometimes is better to ask about needs and then give a answer. Besides i think that more probably is situation that he miss comprehend the meaning of encryption than what he need to use (base64 encoding).

Comment: I try this code, it lookes what I need, but is the resukt alaways 28 characters?

Comment: yes, the result is always the same length regardless of the input. The output is always 28 characters. SHA1 always outputs 160-bit, which is 20 bytes. 20 bytes encoded into base64 is always 28 characters.

Answer (score 10):

(EDIT: I've been assuming you want to both *encrypt* a string, and then *encode* the result as base64, always ending up with the same output length. It would help if you could clarify the question to confirm this or explain what you *do* want if this isn't it.)

Well, there's a pretty simply algorithm which would work given any encryption scheme which always encrypts an input of a fixed length to an output of a fixed length (and there are plenty of those):

- Encode the string as binary using UTF-16 (which will always give the same byte array length for the same string input)
- Pad the binary data to 32 bytes (i.e. the maximum size) using random data
- Add an extra byte at the end (or start) indicating the original length
- Encrypt the binary data (which will always be 33 bytes)
- Convert the result to base64 using `Convert.ToBase64String`

To decrypt, simply reverse the process:

- Convert the base64 text to the encrypted binary data using `Convert.FromBase64String`
- Decrypt the binary data (back to "plaintext" binary)
- Find the length from the first or last byte
- Decode the relevant section of the plaintext binary as UTF-16 text

(Use MSDN to find details of each step, and feel free to ask for help in a specific part. Your choice of encryption algorithm will depend on what you're trying to do, and I'm no expert on that, I'm afraid.)

EDIT: If you only need a hash, then other questions come into play. Would you always want the same string to end up being hashed *to* the same string? That's typically desirable for hashing but not encryption.

Comment: its look fine, if its not important me to decrypt the string, but I want that alaways I give the encrypted string in length of 22 charcters, what can I do? can you attach a code snippet thst demonstrate that?

Comment: @RRR: If you never need to decrypt the string, you're looking for a *hash* rather than encryption. They're completely different algorithms, and you need to give your requirements precisely. See my edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: yes, alaways I want the same string to end up being hased to the same string, but do you know about hasing that alaways give me the output on kixed length - 22 charcters?

Comment: @RRR: Well, straight base64 is never going to give you 22 characters, because it'll always be a multiple of 4. You can get 15 bytes of raw data into 20 characters, or 18 bytes into 24. You could always use extra padding though. Why do you need exactly 22 characters, and if this is really a requirement, why didn't you mention it in the question? Any other requirements we should know about?

Comment: It's not wise to minimize the length of the resulting hash as it will make it easier for any programmer with some brains to get the source string with very basic ways

Comment: and why exactly 22 characters?

Comment: ho, wise or not it is not what I asked, I should exactly 22 characters because I sen the string to another program that can recieve only 22 characters, I can't change it!

Comment: @RRR: 22 characters is not what you originally asked either, and nor is hashing. If you word a question poorly, you shouldn't be surprised when people ask a lot of questions about it.

Comment: maybe, but yoy must agree with me that it's not very important wheter 22 charcters or another number, what that important that I nedd that on fixed length, and I ask it on the basic quastion.

Comment: @RRR: No, it's *very* important - because you said "a fixed length" rather than a *particular* length. In other words, I thought it was fine for answers to come up with any length they wanted, so long as it would give the same length for any input. Add that to the fact that you wanted hashing rather than encryption, and you've basically written a question which would have been *very* hard to answer to your satisfaction, other than by luck.

Comment: 22 base64 chars is very important because it is smaller than the entropy of a 16 unicode chars. So encrypting the input string as asked in your original question is mathematically impossible for the general case. I think you'd need 44 base64 chars to make encryption possible. And the scheme Jon Skeet proposed uses a 44 char output, so it offers the shortest fixed length output possible considering that you said you want to encrypt the input and not hash it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can we have a code sample for this. I tried following the steps mentioned above I am not able to figure out this step "Pad the binary data to 32 bytes (i.e. the maximum size) using random data"

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat: Possibly at some point, but probably not today. (I'm not going to consider it as urgent given that this answer is already 9 years old...) You might want to ask a specific question about that, including what you've already tried.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet appreciate that :)

Comment: @JonSkeet If i get a 8 byte value after UTF-16 encoding in the second step do I have to add 24 more bytes to the original value?

Comment: @ShahidManzoorBhat: Yes, assuming you have the same expected fixed length as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

there is a very clear example in the bottom of this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx)
In more clear words, you need to use [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) with a hashing algorithm such as [SHA1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA) in the previous example. The use of SHA algorithms is to transform any arbitrary length string into a fixed length string and thus if your strings are 1,000,000,000 characters long for example .. you won't need 1,000,000,000 bytes to store them. You will only need to store the resulting string after applying SHA algorithms which is 160 characters in the case of SHA1.  I think in ur case you need only to hash and not to encrypt.The benefit of using SHA algorithms is to secure your encoded data. otherwise, any smart dude will be able to decrypt your encrypted string.

**EDIT**
As you are requiring a resulting hash that is less in length than the famous hashing functions, There are several ways, one famous way is to **XOR** the first 22 bytes of the resulting hash in a **For** loop to the end of the original hash. That will make u end up with a 22-character string. **However** that's not advised as the less characters your hash is, the more chance that you will have a collision or a resulting less-length hash that is similar to another one in your system.

Answer (score -1):

First, "base64" is no encryption, it just is a encoding or transport encapsulation. It is meant to transfer binary data over a transport that allows only ASCII-Characters.

Second, "base64" itsself is variable length, so we have to pad the encoded String manually, and remove the padding for decoding.

However, the following code demonstrates how to accomplish your goal.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace encodingtest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string encoded = Encode("Hello World!", 43);
            Console.WriteLine(encoded);
            Console.WriteLine(Decode(encoded));

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static public string Encode(string source, int length)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(length);
            buffer.Append(System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
            while (buffer.Length < length) {
                buffer.Append('=');
            }
            return buffer.ToString();
        }

        static public string Decode(string encoded) {
            int index = encoded.IndexOf('=');
            if (index >0) {
                encoded = encoded.Substring(0, ((index + 3) / 4) * 4);
            }
            byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, base64 isn't meant to encode *strings* as ASCII characters. It's to encode *arbitrary binary data* as ASCII characters. Big difference.

Comment: ok, its work wanderfull if you the string encoded to the length that sort from the limit, but what can you do when its longer? I know that I can cut the additional charcters but does it is not risk that I accept for diffrent input strings, same encoded output?

Comment: i don't undestand for what here lenght? and why i need to use fixed lenght if it's setted to `43`?

Comment: @user2167382: The original poster wanted to the encoded data to have a fixed length. This 43 is the fixed output length my code generates, as long as the input data is short enough.

Comment: @RRR Yes, of course. If the input string is to long for the fixed output size, you need to handle this condition. In my implementation, I just create a longer output string, but you could also truncate (with data loss) or throw an exception.

Comment: Just because there was an "edit suggestion" yesterday, here some clarification: `(x / 4) * 4` is not equal to `x` with integer arithmetics. The expression `((index + 3) / 4) * 4` does round up the `index` to the next multiple of 4. Test it yourself, e. G. in python:
`>>> for i in range(10): print i, ((i+3)/4)*4
...
0 0
1 4
2 4
3 4
4 4
5 8
6 8
7 8
8 8
9 12`